# Sales force trigger INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

Tags: salesforce

Below code works fine when updating/inserting on Visual Force Page one record at a time, receive error 'Insert failed....INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call'  when using data loader (error pointing to code, 'insert amcRecord').  Would anyone know how to fix?

```
trigger Status on Cl__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    List<AMC__c> amcRecord = new List<AMC__c>();
    for (Cl__c cls: Trigger.new ) 
    {
        Cl__c oldcls = Trigger.oldMap.get(cls.Id);
        if (cls.Status__c == 'Completed' && (oldcls.Status__c != 'Completed'  )) 
        {
            AMC__c newAMC = new AMC__c();
            newAMC.Cl__c = cls.ID;
            newAMC.Default__c = true;  
            amcRecord.add(newAMC); 
            insert amcRecord;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

amcRecord is a list, not a single item, but you're calling insert for every item in the request [which would only be 1 for the UI, but upto 200 with the data loader. You need to move the insert amcRecord line to after the for (... Trigger.new) loop has finished, so that its only called once, e.g.

```
trigger Status on Cl__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    List<AMC__c> amcRecord = new List<AMC__c>();
    for (Cl__c cls: Trigger.new ) 
    {
        Cl__c oldcls = Trigger.oldMap.get(cls.Id);
        if (cls.Status__c == 'Completed' && (oldcls.Status__c != 'Completed'  )) 
        {
            AMC__c newAMC = new AMC__c();
            newAMC.Cl__c = cls.ID;
            newAMC.Default__c = true;  
            amcRecord.add(newAMC); 
        }
    }
    insert amcRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be performing DML inside a loop.This exception comes if you try to insert already inserted record.

```
Account a =new Account();
a.name='Hello';
insert a;
insert a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Changed

```
insert amcRecord;
```

to

```
upsert amcRecord;
```

It seems to be working now.